# Cardinal of a finite union of $G_n$'s

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I was wondering if there is a closed formula or perhaps a recursion that delimits the cardinal of $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n G_k $$

Where $G_k$ represents the k-th roots of 1 in $\mathbb{C}$.
At first I tried to solve the problem for a finite union of prime $G_p$'s, however I was unsuccessful in translating anything to a more general case.

Most of my confusion stems from the cases in which $i|j$ for some $1 \le i < j \le k$, since I can't figure out how to make sure that I am not adding the same element twice

I am absolutely stumped, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a closed form of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)$ where $\varphi(k)$ is the Euler totient function; this is sequence A002088 in OEIS.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_summatory_function) there doesn't seem to be a closed form.